# Multiple linear regression: appending an array on ones to Matrix of features (Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I'm currently learning basics of Data Science online. In one of the session on Multiple Linear Regression using Python, the tutor executed below step to add an array on ones to the Matrix of features ; I did not understand why it is being added. From online forums, it is mentioned that it is added so that model (equation) have a constant offset. But why 1 and not any other values. Does the number of independent variables (3) have any impact on this value

X -> Matrix of features ; number of rows in data set : 50 ; Number of

```
X = np.append(arr = np.ones([50,1]).astype(int), values = X,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To better explain, let's imagine you have only 1 feature stored, and let's say 3 
training examples.

Then, your parameters are:

[image]

And your input variables are:

[image]

If you want to realize a linear classification, you must compute the cost function for each training example i:

[image]

And if you need to vectorize the calculus (for efficiency and code readability), you want to compute the following matricial product:

[image]

**However**, by [definition of the matricial product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition), the number of columns of matrix X should be the same than the number of rows of matrix Theta. Thus, to compute the product but leave the result unchanged, you add a column of ones to the left of matrix X:

[image]

Then, the result for each sample i is the following:

[image]

---

**TLDR**: You need to append a column of ones to `X` for the matricial product X*Theta to be defined. If you were adding any other coefficient `c` instead of `1`, then your constant offset `theta_0` would be multiplied by your coefficient `c`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cost function is the summation of errors between the predicted label and the actual label which we want to minimise. The J function given above is the hypothesis function.